# Why does PDO return integer values from a union select of static values and dynamic values as a string?

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, union

Setup and tested queries:

PDO config

```
$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
```

`user` table

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `admin` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Expected: simple select, returns admin as integer

```
$sql = "SELECT admin FROM user";
$pdo_statement = $pdo->query($sql);
$result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();

var_dump($result);

// > array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["admin"]=> int(1) } } ...
```

Expected: union select with static values, returns admin as integer

```
$sql = "SELECT 0 AS admin FROM user
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS admin FROM user";
$pdo_statement = $pdo->query($sql);
$result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();

var_dump($result);

// > array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["admin"]=> int(1) } } ...
```

Unexpected: union select with mixed static and dynamic values, returns admin as string

```
$sql = "SELECT admin FROM user
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS admin FROM user";
$pdo_statement = $pdo->query($sql);
$result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();

var_dump($result);

// > array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["admin"]=> string(1) "1" } } ...
```

Tested on:

```
Apache 2.4.51
PHP 5.6.40 | 7.4.26 | 8.0.13 | 8.1.0
MySQL 8.0.27
MariaDB 10.6.5
```

Why would the last query return `admin` as a string instead of an integer?
This seems like a PDO bug, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: What do you get if you store the result in a temp table like here: https://dbfiddle.uk/-ObgwIbe ?

Comment: I suppose it's because the data packet has the information on the column type, while for the calculated values it doesn't

Comment: This is not MySQL issue. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZUkC_sZK) - all queries except the most last one (where the output datatype in 2nd subquery is implicitly specified as string-type by explicit literal datatype specifying) returns numeric output column (can be detected by the column adjustment).